# MySQL Order by with two colums mix togather

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
id   |    TOP    |    POS
1    |    60     |    1
2    |    50     |    2
3    |    40     |    3
4    |    30     |    4
5    |    20     |    5
6    |    10     |    6
```

and I need result like this:

```
id   |    TOP    |    POS
1    |    60     |    1
6    |    10     |    6
2    |    50     |    2
5    |    20     |    5
3    |    40     |    3
4    |    30     |    4
```

Basicaly I need order result by TOP column DESC but between each line put result from order by POS DESC column.

I tried use MOD but result was wrong

```
SELECT * FROM (
select 
    @row := @row + 1 as row,
    a.*
from table a
order by TOP desc
) t ORDER BY IF(MOD(row, 2) = 1, TOP, POS);
```

Comment: For what even do you need to look your result set like this?

Comment: You just changed the question, and I think you should do a better job of explaining why you need this output.  I see a very convoluted query needed to get this output, and I would rather not write it.

Comment: Some things are better done on application level. There this would be easy to do. A database is not the right place for such things.

Comment: This would be very simple though, did MySQL feature standard SQL's `ROW_NUMBER`. I think this is announced for MySQL 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you need two sortkeys: the row ordered by TOP and the row ordered by POS. This means tow queries you must join.

Then sort first by the lesser of these two keys (TOP60/POS1 has row #1 for TOP, TOP10/POS6 has row #1 for POS, so these two come first), and then by the TOP key (so TOP60/POS1 has precedence over TOP10/POS6).

```
select a1.*
from
(
  select 
    @rowtop := @rowtop + 1 as row,
    a.*
  from mytable a
  cross join (select @rowtop := 0) vars
  order by top desc
) a1 
join
(
  select 
    @rowpos := @rowpos + 1 as row,
    a.*
  from mytable a
  cross join (select @rowpos := 0) vars
  order by pos desc
) a2 using(id)
order by least(a1.row, a2.row), a1.row;
```

REXTESTER DEMO: http://rextester.com/ZKOL97078